ROS 2 Service Future - Why underscored vars _done and _result?
My ROS 2 Humble robot makes an async service request /dock to a "docking_node" and saves the "future" provided at the request.
"""
# dave_interfaces.srv.Dock.srv 
# Request
---
# Result
bool is_docked
bool is_charging
bool success
"""

self.dock_svc_future = self.dock_svc_client.call_async(self.dock_svc_req)


The robot then periodically checks the dock_svc_future to see if the dock request is done (and the service result is available to be read).
I expected to need to check dock_svc_future.done and then read dock_svc_future.result, but the future vars are actually _done and _result:


2024-06-12 15:00:06.588 dave_main_cb: exec undocking

self.undock_svc_future: {'_done': False, '_cancelled': False, '_result': None, '_exception': None, '_exception_fetched': False, '_callbacks': [<bound method Client.remove_pending_request of <rclpy.client.Client object at 0x7fff7eaa7340>>], '_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fff79990780>, '_executor': <function _fake_weakref at 0x7fff8092b250>}

...

2024-06-12 15:00:09.588 dave_main_cb: exec undocking

self.undock_svc_future: {'_done': True, '_cancelled': False, '_result': dave_interfaces.srv.Undock_Response(is_docked=False, success=True), '_exception': None, '_exception_fetched': False, '_callbacks': [], '_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fff79990780>, '_executor': <weakref at 0x7fff79b7fe70; to 'MultiThreadedExecutor' at 0x7fff7eaa7550>}

undock_svc_future.result._success True  is_docked: False

Am I doing something wrong that the vars are prefaced with underscore?


I expected to need to check dock_svc_future.done and then read dock_svc_future.result, but the future vars are actually _done and _result

I don't think anything is wrong.
rclpy.task.Future (see here) has  .done() and .result() getter functions that will return the "private" member variables _done and _result. I'd use those.
The member function .result() does a bit more and throws an exception if it caught one that was raised.
